# Force kink-free paths

Tags: vector, gimp, path, plugin

I want to model a railroad line by using paths from GIMP. Of course rail tracks *cannot have any kinks.* Therefore I have been adjusting the handles of each vertex to have the same angle:

[image: Tangential handles]

While that works, it is really inconvenient, inaccurate and annoying. **Is there a feature/plugin in GIMP to force the handles to have the same angle, i.e. to forbid any kinks in paths?**

Comment: You *might* want to look into a vector application - Illustrator, Inkscape - they'll handle paths better. It's my understanding Gimp, much like Photoshop, is raster-based even it it has some path operations. But perhaps I'm incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to move each handle separately.

In GIMP, hold down the shift key as you click and drag on a handle, this will constrain the other handle to the same angle, and keep the curve smooth.

I agree with the comment from Scott. A vector image editor would be better for this kind of work. GIMP is really a raster image editor. Inkscape(dot)org is a free and OpenSource vector image editor.

Answer (score 0):

There is  a ["smooth path" plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/20069). Basically, you can create a polygonal path, and call the plugin to adjust the handles for maximum smoothness (in other words, it finds the smoothest path that goes through your anchors).

[image]